# Operators in JCCD (argument Mismatch) in AcceptFileNames Class

Tags: java, jccd

I am building an application that implementing an API that named Java Code Clone Detector(JCDD) from this website http://jccd.sourceforge.net/getting_started.html. It gives me an error that I am not understand. The code is like this :

```
public void jalankanAlgoritma(File FileUtama, List<String> fileJlist) {
    APipeline<?> detector = new ASTDetector();
List<String> jListListnya;

    if (!jListListnya.isEmpty() || jListListnya == null) {

        // looping of compare
        for (String JlistList1 : jListListnya) { //Jlist1 is a swing component
            JCCDFile[] files = {
                new JCCDFile(new File(FileUtama.getAbsolutePath())),
                new JCCDFile(new File(JlistList1))};
          detector.setSourceFiles(files);
          detector.addOperator(new GeneralizeMethodDeclarationNames()); // Method Names
          detector.addOperator(new GeneralizeVariableNames()); //Variable names

            detector.addOperator(new GeneralizeClassDeclarationNames()); // Class name
            detector.addOperator(new AcceptFileNames()); // This is error
            APipeline.printSimilarityGroups(detector.process());

           }
    }
}
```

The netbeans told me that `No suitable method found for addOperator(AcceptFileNames). Method Apipeline.addOperator(Aproccessor is not applicable)`

What means this statement and how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The `addOperator` method requires a parameter of a type which is a super class of `GeneralizeClassDeclarationNames`.  When you pass a parameter of type `AcceptFileNames`, this is incorrect, because there is no method `addOperator` which matches the method signature with  `AcceptFileNames` as a parameter. You need to make sure that the AcceptFileNames class inherits from the same class as `GeneralizeClassDeclarationNames`.

Read up on the concept of Overloading.